# Custom menu for a site page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have news on a SharePoint site. Every news is a separate site page and stored in the site page library. I have a column in this library with a button for each news/row that when clicked, will promote the specific site page/news to teams. So far so good.

However, is it possible to integrate the value of this column inside the site page menu?

[image]

Above I am inside a news article with its specific menu. Is it possible to customise this menu with its document library list/column value?

Comment: Try application customizer in SPFx - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions

Comment: @harshal gite: Does application customizer has placeholder for site page ribbon?

Comment: I was wondering it too. I have used it previously to make a site level custom mega menu using the "top placeholder" but not sure if it has for the site page menu.